# how to update column names for started something in sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to replace some column values but i'm getting the error:

> ORA-00911: invalid character

My query:

```
SELECT REPLACE (email, ‘.com’, ‘.net’) FROM emp;
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: I don't know if you're using a word processing program (e.g. Microsoft Word, OpenOffice Writer, etc) to edit code, but if you are - DON'T! Word processing software is concerned with the appearance of documents, and will thus use those paired-apostrophe characters instead of single-quotes. This will not work well in a programming context where the actual characters used matter quite a bit. Get yourself a good code editor - there's a ton of them out there, many of them free - and use it when editing programs. Best of luck.

Answer (score 4):

Use `'` instead of `‘`

```
SELECT REPLACE (email, '.com', '.net') FROM emp;
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrong appostrophies

```
SELECT REPLACE(email, '.com', '.net') 
FROM emp
```